# iOS UISearchBar's keyboard partly hides tableView

Tags: ios

I have an `UIView` (implementing `UISearchBarDelegate`), on which I have `UIImageView`, `UITableView` and `UISearchbar`.

When searching, the `tableView` with search results gets partly hidden by keyboard. How could I make the `tableView` to scroll when keyboard appears?

Maybe I should just make the view frame smaller for the time the search is being implemented. On the other hand, as I've read, this approach is not recommended.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should register your view to be an observer of the `UIKeyboard` notifications. When the keyboard changes its state, a notification is sent and from the notification object you can retrieve the keyboard frame, which allows you to resize your table view frame accordingly. As soon as the keyboard disappears, you will get a new notification and then you will be able to resize the table view again. Besides these notifications (read the developer library doc for details) allow you to synchronized perfectly your view resizing with the keyboard animations.

Note that you can also use the system defined `UISearchDisplayController` object which takes care of these details (and other) for you. It's a strange beast (it's not a UIViewController subclass for instance) but if you learn how to use it will save you a lot of extra work.

Comment: Thank you, this answer is helpful. I used only UIKeyboardDidShowNotification, because I can resize the tableView back again in the method which is called when the user clicks Done Searching button.